# MongoDb : Regex in Java Slow

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

So, if I run the following query it takes just under 5 seconds

```
db.RawURLS.find({"url" : { $regex : /^https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org/ }}).count()
```

If I do what I believe is the same in Java, it takes a lot longer

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mainMongo);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDatabase);
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(urlTable);

Document regQuery = new Document();
regQuery.append("$regex", "^(?)" + Pattern.quote("https://en.wikipedia.org/"));
regQuery.append("$options", "i");

Document findQuery = new Document();
findQuery.append("url", regQuery);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(findQuery).iterator();
```

Have I got an error?

I have a field called URL, which I want to check to see if it starts with XYZ for example.  The URL is indexed.

Comment: I believe your Java code is incomplete, since I can't see where you actually fetch the results. Also, have you tried instrumenting your code to find out which part takes the most time? Is it possible that it's because of network overhead?

Comment: My bad, updated

Comment: It feels like the Java Code is doing a COLSCAN instead of using an index

Comment: How many items in your database are we talking about here?

Comment: is this `(?)` a new regex syntax ?

Comment: 900 million records

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can provide what MongoDB printed in its logs when you try to run the two queries, so it's easier to determine what MongoDB actually did and what are the differences between the execution of the two queries. Slow queries (>100ms) will be logged by default.

Comment: I see that in your raw query you are doing a count(), but in java code you fetch all the results...

Comment: How would I show the logs